# How do you plant shallots?

Tags: vegetables, onion-sets

I've bought some out of season shallot sets ( whatever a set is ) but I'm just wondering how to plant them.  They appear to have cloves but the videos I've seen suggest that you plant them as a bulb and don't divide them into cloves like garlic to plant.

So, it's now early summer and I'm going to plant them anyway, but is there some advantage to planting them as bulbs?

Answer (score 1):

No...plant them like you would garlic cloves.  Each will make a plant.  The entire bulb of cloves would probably mean all will die but one...Shallots are so dang hardy and easy to grow.  Unlike garlic that you need to start the season before, shallots will be productive anytime you start them.  In your dang heaven, they might even last through your winter with a bit of mulching.  Have you tried garlic?  It is early summer for you, ah man...if our ship comes in you just might have a visitor! Elizabeth Conway? Plant your sets, divided into cloves, twice as deep as those cloves are long. That is what I say anyway.  Others say to plant only as deep as the widest part of the clove.  I've done both and every single clove did just fine.

Comment: Do you know went they are called sets?

Comment: Ummmm, is this a trick question?  I assumed...because they are a collection of cloves making up the bulb?  I am getting ready to eat apple wood smoked prime rib for dinner and sippin' sake!

Comment: I don't know the answer.  Why aren't garlic bulbs called sets then?

Comment: They aren't?  Now you've got my curiosity going again...arghhh~